# Is it close paren, closed paren, or closing paren?

Tags: lisp, parentheses

What are the correct terms for `(` and `)` in Lisp?

- open paren
- opening paren
- closing paren
- closed paren
- close paren

Are they all accepted terms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_ac.htm) calls them:

SP06        (      left parenthesis, or open parenthesis
SP07        )      right parenthesis, or close parenthesis